# Image in viewport different from final render AND Ctrl + S won't save their new changes

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Good Afternoon.
Rendered image in  my viewport is different from final render. Nothing is hidden nor disabled. Viewport -[image]

Rendered File (Max Samples = 10) [image]

The interesting part is that, it don't matter how many times I SAVE or SAVE AS, each blender file  opens with this same viewport  after so many adjustments. [image].

Let  me break it down;

Desktop > Strawberry Folder >

- Lotion Two.blend (Has 2 lotion bottles)
- Lotion Three.blend (Adjusted to have 3 lotion bottles)
- Lotion Four.blend (Adjusted to have 4 lotion bottles)
- Lotion Five.blend (Adjusted to have 5 lotion bottles)

But each time these .blend files are opened, they all show up as 2 lotion bottles in the viewport. Now I have to start duplicating and rearranging their positions over and over and over again. Is this a technical problem?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of an expanded Collection 2 and 3, and also include the filter icon :: Display Viewport?  This to see any differences in Viewport vs Rendering settings

Comment: Check that you don't have *Holdout* set on any of the desired objects (although you should then see a render with an object replaced with "no alpha" pixels, that I don't see).

Comment: Maybe some objects have animation keys on their Location ?

Comment: @thibsert Yes. The  keyframes were the  problem. I feel so embarrased right now. . Thank you so so so much.